# Show clock with CST time in html page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show clock with CST time format in HTML page using JavaScript? It should show exact CST time in this format "02 Jul 2015 10:34:45 PM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way but i was unable to find anything. This works though.

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];

d = new Date();
    //set the offset
    var utcOffset = -6;
    //get utc
    var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    //create new date adjusting by the utcOffset to get local date/time
    var localDate = new Date(utc + (3600000 * (utcOffset+1)));
    //check if one character if so format as two by adding leading 0.
    var formatDay = (localDate.getDate().length > 1) ? localDate.getDate() : '0' + localDate.getDate();
    //string everything together
    var fullDate = formatDay + ' ' + monthNames[localDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + localDate.getFullYear() + ' ' + localDate.toLocaleTimeString();

$('#div1').html(fullDate);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ojga6a5u/

Comment: Thanks @Sean Wessell but this script will not work if I will access my site in different time zone